# Why do 3D models have duplicate vertex positions with different uv coords

Tags: 3d, blender, directx-11, vertex-shader, collada

I am experimenting with exporting the Collada format from Blender, and with using more complex objects and texturing, I have noticed during the index "p" section, it will list the same vertex information but using different normals and uv coords.

**Two main questions that I feel are pretty important.**

1:  Why?  Shouldnt it only have 1 vertex position and 1 UV coord for that position?

2(the most important question of all): What happens if this vertex information gets put into the Vertex Shader out of order?  For example, Index 1 vertex, and index 10 vertex share the same Position, but have different Normals and UV Coords. What if Index 10 went first, and then Index 1?  And vice versa, does this change anything inside of the Pixel Shader?  How does this effect the rest of the pipeline?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vertex is defined by the combination of all information that defines it. So your vertices are five dimensional: (x, y, z, u, v). For any two vertices, if u1 != u2 or v1 != v2 they are not the same vertex. Fixed-pipeline GPUs didn't support the extra level of indirection that would come if you wanted to say "vertex is position A plus texture position B plus normal C plus ...", and it is still not standard to add that level of indirection with programmable GPUs because it usually amounts to spending more on memory bandwidth than it saves. You could, but people generally don't.

A vertex shader has no concept of where the vertex it is processing fell in the ordering; as long as the geometry pipeline keeps track then no problems ensue.

Comment: Great answer, but what about question 1?

Comment: GPUs work with 'interleaved vertex data' meaning that all per-vertex data is packed into the same block which is defined by a format and a stride. If you want to have the same position with different normals, UVs, bone indices, or any other per-vertex data you have to duplicate it (also known as 'splitting'). GPUs use "arrays of structures", not "structures of arrays". Even when using multiple streams of vertex buffers, you only have a single index for all buffers per vertex

Comment: Right. My answer to question one is: no vertices are duplicated. Vertex (x, y, z, u1, v1) and vertex (x, y, z, u2, v2) are different vertices, because they have different (u, v)s.

Comment: Why does a 3D Model have same vertex but different UV?  If the texture is just wrapping ontop of the model why does it need to do this?

Comment: If it has a different UV, it is not the same vertex. It is a different vertex. A model may have two vertices at the same location either because it needs to map a discontinuity in its source texture — avoiding those is in the general case impossible, e.g. how would you map a figure of eight? — or possibly because it uses more than one texture and the coordinates don't line up.

Comment: @Tommy Thank you.  This is very helpful when building our own 3D format.